# How to add text in editor access notification email?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I wrote a script to add editors to a spreadsheet but I want to add text to the email sent to them.
In this image shown the step where I can write a message to the email receiver who I gave access to.

```
    function send_emails(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  for (var i=1;i<=lr;i++){
    var ID = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var MCP = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    var MCVP_1 = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    DriveApp.getFileById(ID).addEditors([MCP,MCVP_1]);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is possible if you sue the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) instead of `DriveApp`

It is based on the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive) and allows you to use the method [Permissions: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert).

**Sample:**

```js
function send_emails(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  for (var i=1;i<=lr;i++){
    var ID = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var MCP = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    var MCVP_1 = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    var resource1 = {
      "role": "writer",
      "type": "user",
      "value": MCP
    }
    var resource2 = {
      "role": "writer",
      "type": "user",
      "value": MCVP_1
    }   
    var optionalArgs = {
      "sendNotificationEmails":true,
      "emailMessage": "This is my custom message"
    }
    Drive.Permissions.insert(resource1, ID, optionalArgs);
    Drive.Permissions.insert(resource2, ID, optionalArgs);
  }
}
```

**Important:**

You need to manually [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) the `Advanced Drive Service` before running the code.